# boost_python import error: module does not define init function

Tags: boost-python

First off: I looked at the related questions, but they are not very helpful unfortunately. I'm trying to wrap an enum and a class from an external library.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

#include <libvpsc/rectangle.h>
using vpsc::Rectangle;
using vpsc::Dim;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(adaptagrams)
{
    enum_<Dim>("dim")
        .value("x", vpsc::XDIM)
        .value("y", vpsc::YDIM)
        .value("unset", vpsc::UNSET)
    ;

    class_<Rectangle>("Rectangle",
        init<double, double, double, double, optional<bool> >())

        .add_property("centerX", &Rectangle::getCentreX)
        .add_property("centerY", &Rectangle::getCentreY)
        .add_property("width", &Rectangle::width, &Rectangle::set_width)
        .add_property("height", &Rectangle::height, &Rectangle::set_height)
    ;
}
```

and compile with:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c adaptagrams.cpp -o adaptagrams.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,adaptagrams.so -o adaptagrams.so adaptagrams.o -lpython2.7  -lboost_python -lvpsc
```

However, when I try to import the .so module, I get an error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_adaptagrams)
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** When I restart Python and try the import, the first error I get is:

```
ImportError: ./adaptagrams.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8topology13computeStressERKSt6vectorIPNS_4EdgeESaIS2_EE
```

When I try it again, the 2nd one is the dynamic import from above (2.7) and a segfault (3.2). Boost is compiled against both 2.7 and 3.2 and I am linking the right ones on each approach.

**Update 2:** The tutorial code from the boost_python page works:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct Hello
{
    Hello(std::string msg): msg(msg) {}
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(constructor)
{
    class_<Hello>("Hello", init<std::string>())
        .def("greet", &Hello::greet)
        .def("set", &Hello::set)
    ;
}
```

Same compilation:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c constructor.cpp -o constructor.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,constructor.so -o constructor.so constructor.o -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing library.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The name used in `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` must match the name of the `.so` library you generate and import into **python**.

Comment: do you know where in the documentation this is stated?

Comment: Interesting: I had to do `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libhello)` whereas my CMake settings called my library 'hello'. This seems to conflict with the Boost.Python docs.

Comment: The reason for this is that cmake usually prepends "lib". This can be changed when you set the properties of the library target, more specifically when you change the [PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/PREFIX.html) property.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this exception before. I got it using Visual Studio on windows, so things might be a little different over in unix-oid land but:

Two Possibilities:

Debug/Release miss-match:
You are trying to import a debug build of your module into a release build of python (or vice-versa). The solution is to include `boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp` instead of `Python.h`. This will fix some includes and defines to make it possible to do what you want.

Python/Boost.Python version miss-match:
Boost.Python is compiled against one specific version of python. You are using it with a different version. For example: you seem to be using python 2.7. Your boost_python library might be compiled against python 2.6. Yes, this means that your module can only work with one version of python at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but the other include doesn't help and Boost is already compiled against python2.7 and python3.2 (tried linking/including with both, same error).

Comment: Ah, then it must be something else. I can't really help you. I would suggest looking at linker type things.

Comment: And now I see below you did and you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers (in case another unfortunate soul runs unto this), make sure you're not accidentally compiling with the `-fvisibility=hidden` flag.

Doing so seems to strip the init function from the binary in both g++ / clang++.

**Background info**

In my case I had some trouble integrating some wrappers made with Boost.Python  into a project. When built with the project's build-system I'd get the same runtime-error as OP (as opposed to building it with my proof-of-concept `Makefile` where it worked just fine).

Comparing the symbol tables with `nm -g foo.so | grep Py` showed me that in the non-working case the `PyInit_*` function was completely absent. Doing some comparison between compilation flags led me to `-fvisibilty=hidden` being the culprit.