# ImportError dynamic module does not define init function (boost.python)

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

Thank you for see this topic. I tried to use `boost.python` but now this error happens.

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function
>   (initlatticepy)

I checked some questions in web and some answers said that BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE name and filename must be the same. (ex. [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400244/boost-python-import-error-module-does-not-define-init-function) said)
But I have already done it.

This is my code `lattice.h`,

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(latticepy)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<lattice::Lattice>("Lattice")
    .def("loadProperties", &lattice::Lattice::loadProperties)
    .def("train", &lattice::Lattice::train)
    .def_readonly("hmm_", &lattice::Lattice::hmm_);
}
```

and build code.

```
g++ -I`python -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import *; print get_python_inc()'` -DPIC -shared -fPIC -o latticepy.so lattice.h -g -O0 -lfst -ldl -lboost_system -lboost_python -std=c++11 -lpython2.7
```